# Number of 5 letter words over a 4 letter group using each letter at least once

Tags: combinatorics

Given the set $\{a,b,c,d\}$ how many 5 letter words can be formed such that each letter is used at least once?

I tried solving this using inclusion - exclusion but got a ridiculous result:

$4^5 - \binom{4}{1}\cdot 3^5 + \binom{4}{2}\cdot 2^5 - \binom{4}{3}\cdot 1^5 = 2341$

It seems that the correct answer is:

$\frac{5!}{2!}\cdot 4 = 240$

Specifically, the sum of the number of permutations of aabcd, abbcd, abccd and abcdd.

I'm not sure where my mistake was in the inclusion - exclusion approach. My universal set was all possible 5 letter words over a set of 4 letters, minus the number of ways to exclude one letter times the number of 5 letter words over a set of 3 letters, and so on.

Where's my mistake?

Comment: How did you get 2341? Perhaps if you show your working there we can point out the underlying mistake.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your mistake is in the arithmetic. What you think comes out to 2341 really does come out to 240.

$4^5=1024$, $3^5=243$, $2^5=32$, $1024-(4)(243)+(6)(32)-4=1024-972+192-4=1216-976=240$

Comment: Wow, duhhh... I probably hit $5^5$ on the calculator by accident...

Comment: Could I solve this with generating functions also?

Comment: I don't know. You could let $a_n$ be the number of $n$-letter words on an $(n-1)$-letter alphabet using each letter exactly once, try to find a recurrence satisfied by the sequence $a_n$, and then try to solve that recurrence by generating functions. More generally, the problems is a special case of finding the number of *onto* maps from an $n$-element set to a $k$-element set. The answer to that question can be expressed in terms of Stirling numbers of the second kind. There is a lot of information out there for those numbers, possibly including generating functions.

Comment: @RobertS.Barnes, take a look at Wilf's delicious "generationfunctionology" <http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html>, it gives a formulation of the inclusion-exclusion principle using generating functions. As a bonus, instead of the traditional mess you get a _very_ simple relation that can be used to compute many results directly or derive the mess when required in a few lines.

Answer (score 2):

I am writing this answer **in case you also need to know about the second way:** (*Ignore if you know the details of the second method.*)

Since you need to use each letter atleast once you really have choice only over one of the letters. This can be chosen in $4$ ways and they can be permuted in $\dfrac{5!}{2!}$ ways.

Hence the number of words, is, $\dfrac{5!}{2!} \cdot 4 =240$ words. $\blacksquare$

Comment: Could you employ this approach for - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2704480?

Answer (score 0):

Another take on @Aryabhata's solution: If we have the set $\{a, a, b, c, d\}$, it can be permuted in $\binom{5}{2 \; 1 \; 1 \; 1}$ ways (multinomial coefficient, lower story records the numbers of repetitions of each symbol), and as the duplicated letter can be selected in 4 ways the result is:
$$
\binom{5}{2 \; 1 \; 1 \; 1} \cdot 4 = \frac{5!}{2! 1! 1! 1!} \cdot 4 = \frac{5!}{2!} \cdot 4 = 240
$$

Comment: Could you employ this approach for - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2704480?