# How many $5$ letter words that use letters from the $3$ letter set ${a,b,c}$ in which each letter occurs at least once?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations, inclusion-exclusion

How many $5$ letter words that use letters from the $3$ letter set ${a,b,c}$ in which each letter occurs at least once ?

---

Can Inclusion - Exclusion Principle be applied here and Why ?

Comment: See also: [Number of 5 letter words over a 3 letter alphabet using each letter at least once](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/108994)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Inclusion/Exclusion Principle as follows:

- Include the number of words with at most $\color\red3$ types of letters: $\binom{3}{\color\red3}\cdot\color\red3^5$
- Exclude the number of words with at most $\color\red2$ types of letters: $\binom{3}{\color\red2}\cdot\color\red2^5$
- Include the number of words with at most $\color\red1$ types of letters: $\binom{3}{\color\red1}\cdot\color\red1^5$

The answer is therefore:

$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{2}(-1)^n\cdot\binom{3}{3-n}\cdot(3-n)^5$$

Comment: But, I have a doubt how to know that inclusion exclusion works here ? I have heard only in case of derangements .

Comment: @Garrick: I'm not sure how I could possibly explain to you why PIE works in this question but not in some other question, when I have no reference to that other question whatsoever.

Comment: Okk !! If I remove the line "Can Inclusion - Exclusion Principle be applied here and Why ?". Then, how to know :)

Comment: @Garrick: I don't know if there's a general method for parsing the text of a question and determining whether it can be solved only by PIE, also by PIE or neither. I just use (my) common sense.

Comment: I got it, that why you applied IE. Thanks !!