# Number of Strings / Number with $ n $ Characters / Digits Built with $ k $ Size Alphabet with each Element of the Alphabet Appearing At Least Once

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

## Question

Given an Alphabet of size $ k $ how many strings / numbers of length $ n \geq k $ with each element of the Alphabet appearing at least once?

## Example

Example of specific case.
The Alphebet being $ \left\{ 1, 2, 3, 4 \right\} $ and $ n  = 7 $.
Then the answer is the number of 7 digits numbers with the digits $ 1, 2, 3, 4 $ appearing at least once in them.

## Approach

I thought one could build something in Dynamic Programming approach with Inclusion / Exclusion.

Let's define $ F \left( n, k \right) $ as the answer for $ n, k $.
Then $ F \left( n, k + 1 \right) = {\left( k + 1 \right)}^{n} - \sum_{i = 1}^{k} \binom{k + 1}{i} F \left( n, i \right) $. Where simply we took all numbers of $ n $ digits and removed those built with smaller Alphabet.

I'm not sure about $ F \left( n + 1, k \right) $.

Feel free to give any kind of answer / approach which deals with it.

Comment: What does "at least any" mean?

Comment: @WilliamElliot, I revised it. Is it clear now? What I mean is you must use each element of the Alphabet at least once. That's the constraint. Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What we need to count is the number of [surjective functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surjective_function) from a set with $n$ elements (the positions in the string) to a set with $k$ elements (the characters in the alphabet).

If there were no restrictions, we would have $k$ choices for each of the $n$ positions in the string.  Hence, there are $n^k$ possible strings.  From these,
we must exclude those strings in which fewer can $k$ characters appear.  There are $\binom{k}{j}$ ways to exclude $j$ of the $k$ characters from the string and $(k - j)^n$ ways to fill the string of length $n$ with the remaining $k - j$ characters in the alphabet.  By the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), the number of such strings is 
$$\sum_{j = 0}^{k} (-1)^j\binom{k}{j}(k - j)^n$$
In your example of strings of length $7$ over the alphabet $\{1, 2, 3, 4\}$, we obtain
$$\sum_{j = 0}^{4} (-1)^j\binom{4}{j}(4 - j)^7 = 4^7 - \binom{4}{1}3^7 + \binom{4}{2}2^7 - \binom{4}{3}1^7 + \binom{4}{4}0^7$$
strings in which each number is used at least once.

Comment: Hi, First thank you. Why not make the sum until $ k - 1 $? I will try validate my approach through your solution.

Comment: When $n = 0$ and $k > 0$, we should get no strings of length $0$ that include all of the letters of the alphabet.  Without making the upper index equal to $k$, we will not obtain the correct answer.

Comment: Well I asked about the case $ n \geq k $. I need to read more about [Inclusion Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) (Better yet, reading examples how to use it in practice).

Comment: The point I was making is that the formula should work for any nonnegative integers $n$ and $k$.

Comment: Yea, I got it at first. Thank You.